# How to implement JavaScript Array shift() in java ArrayList

Tags: javascript, java

**javascript :**

```
this.arr.shift();
let head = this.arr[this.arr.length-1].copy();
head.x += this.xdir;
head.y += this.ydir;
this.arr.push(head);
```

So arr is a array with object `PVector` which has the x and y value.
what the shift function does is removes the first element of the array and re-indices all elements from 0.

**Java**

```
PVector head = body.get(0);
for (int i = 0; i < body.size();i++)
{
  if(i < body.size()-1)
  {
    body.add(i,body.remove(i+1));
  } 
}
head.x += xdir;
head.y += ydir;
body.remove(body.size()-1);
body.add(head);
```

This is the code in java but it doesn't work same as javascript code. I couldn't figure out what's wrong or Is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: Uh, wouldn't [`arrayList.remove(0)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove-int-) in Java be the entire implementation of the JS `array.shift()`? Or are you required to create the algorithm yourself?

Comment: Why not use queue in java? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html#poll()

Answer (score 0):

I think that instead of using for loop you can try something like this:

```
if (body.size() > 0){
    body.remove(0);
}

if (body.size() > 0) {
    PVector head = body.get(body.size()-1);
[...]
}
```